# FabricUI and angularJS uif-textfield issue

Tags: angularjs, office-ui-fabric

I have requirement where i have to show 1/4 th of the value which i entered in first textbox(test1) in my second textbox using fabric UI textbox.

First Textbox

```
<uif-textfield uif-type="number" ng-model="Test1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty"></uif-textfield>
```

when i use normal input field this works fine

```
<input type="number" value='{{Test/4}}'  ng-model="test2">
```

but when i try to use the same expression in fabric UI textfield it does not work

Second textbox

```
 <uif-textfield uif-type="number"  ng-model="test2" value="{{Test1/4}}"></uif-textfield>
```

Any pointers on how to make it work in fabric UI textbox will be helpful

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't appear to be related to `fabricjs`. Could you please retag as `office-ui-fabric` instead?

Comment: what does "it does not work" mean, exactly?  What is the expected result and the actual result you are seeing?  Also, setting `value` in the HTML is probably not right, you should be setting the Property of the `ng-model` (e.g. `test2`) to your value in the JavaScript instead.

Comment: expected result is if i enter 60 in the first textbox ,15 should come in the second textbox. If i try with "<input>" tag as shown above i get the expected result. But if i use " <uif-textfield>" tag i am not getting value as expected.I need to use <uif-textfield> and make this work. Any pointers will be helpfull